# Obj-C Calculator - Radians to Degrees

Tags: objective-c, ios, trigonometry

I've been watching the Stanford CS193P lectures and I've been working on the assignment calculator. I got through the first assignment fairly easily, and I'm trying to do the extra credit for the assignment now. I'm stuck however at one of the extra credit questions:

*Implement a user-interface for choosing whether the operand to sin() or cos() is
considered radians or degrees. When you call sin(x) in the C library, x is assumed
to be in radians (i.e. 0 to 2π goes around the circle once), but users might want to
enter 180 and press the sin button and get 0 instead of -0.8012 (which is the sine of
180 radians). You could use a UIButton for this and switch out the titleLabel’s
text each time the UIButton is pressed, but a better way would be to see if you can
figure out how to use a UISwitch by reading the documentation (if you dare!).*

I implemented a UISwitch and hooked it up as an IBOutlet. When I perform an 'operation', I check if the switch is on or off and pass this to my model along with the operation to perform. In my sin and cos cases, I do the following:

```
else if ([operation isEqual:@"sin"])
{
    if (radians) {
        operand = sin(operand);
    }
    else {
        operand = sin(operand) * (180 / M_PI);
    }

}
// similar for cos
```

If `radians` (which is a BOOL: YES = radians, no = degrees), then I perform the operation as usually; if the user puts the switch to 'degrees', I want to return the value in degrees, as the assignment states: *users might want to enter 180 and press the sin button and get 0 instead of -0.8012 (which is the sine of 180 radians).*

However, this code doesn't fully work. When I put the switch to degrees and do `sin 180` it returns a value of more or less `-45`. Something is wrong there; and I'm not really sure what. I have looked up how to do the conversion and I think I'm doing it right, but apparently not.

I realise this is perhaps better suited for math.stackexchange, but since there was some code I wanted to post I put it here. Can someone provide some advice on the best way to implement this? It's been a while since I even worked with cos or sin, radians and degrees.

Thanks!

Comment: I retagged as homework, but then I realized you're doing this for fun.  Hope I didn't ruin anything.

Comment: It's okay; it's kind of a homework-y question anyway. Don't worry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you define operand?

Are you sure that `operand` is a CGFloat and not a memory address?

How are you formatting your output? If you are using %e it will output in scientific notation...try doing %f

Comment: `double operand;` in my model's header file. It works fine when doing the normal sin/cos, just not when I try to convert to degrees. All the other operand-'operations' work fine aswell. I doubt it's a code-problem, more of a logical thinking problem on my part.

Comment: Try using CGFloat, it should get help with the roundoff error that Steve mentioned

Comment: Still getting the 122...e-16 with CGFloat. How do I know which one to use? When double, when float, when CGFloat? Are there rules for that? Thanks.

Comment: No prob :) You'd be surprised how many times I've scratched my head over that one ;)

Comment: What is the exact difference between `%g`, `%e` and `%f`? I tried googling for it, but that pretty much failed.

Comment: http://www.itsjustpoison.com/blog/2008/12/01/nslog-format-specifiers That should tell you and then some :)

Answer (score 8):

Did you perhaps mean `operand = sin(operand * M_PI / 180);`?

Comment: That still doesn't return 1 when I do sin 180 degrees. I'm so confused here, haha.

Comment: sin 180 degrees should be zero. cos 180 degrees is 1.

Comment: Yeah, I misread what the assignment said. Was a typo, I meant 0. Anyway, it returns a floating point number. 122465e-16.

Comment: That particular floating point is indicative of roundoff error. Which is close enough to 0.

Comment: I'm still getting the 1.22465e-16 with CGFloat. Is there a way to just make this 0? Kind of new to this stuff.

Comment: Just pop it into an integer.  `int degrees = sin(operand * M_PI / 180);`.  It will just truncate to the units place like you're wanting.

Comment: sin(x) is always between -1 and 1, though. And so you'll almost always be getting 0. :P

Comment: whoops, forgot about the negative.  Forget what I said! :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this - It works for me:

```
    if ([operation isEqual:@"sin"])
    {
        operand = (operand * M_PI/180); // first convert the operand from radians to degrees then perform the operation
        operand = sin(operand);
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
operand = sin(operand * (M_PI/180));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
sin( operand ) / 180.0 * M_PI
```